# Dual of $l^p$ spaces

Tags: lp-spaces, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

Let $H:l^{p'}(\mathbb{N})\times l^p(\mathbb{N})\to \mathbb{K}$ defined as $H(y,x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}x_ny_n$.

This application is bilinear and continous.

Let $a_H:l^{p'}(\mathbb{N})\to (l^p(\mathbb{N})'$ defined as $\langle a_H(y),x\rangle=H(y,x)$. This application is linear and continuous, with norm less or equal than $\Vert y\Vert_{L^{p'}(\mathbb{N})}$. We say that $(l^{p}(\mathbb{N})'$ identifies with $l^{p'}(\mathbb{N})$ if $a_H$ is an isomorphism.

1. When $p=1$, show that $H$ helps to identify $(l^1(\mathbb{N}))'$ to $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$.
2. Using the sequence
   $$x_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\bar{y_k}}{\vert y_k\vert}\vert y_k\vert^{\frac{1}{p-1}}e_n$$
   where $e_n$ has a $1$ in its $n$-th place, show that if there is linear form $L\in (l^p(\mathbb{N}))'$, then $y_n=\langle L,e_n\rangle$ defines an element of $l^{p'}(\mathbb{N})$. Conclude.

**My work**

1. Done (injectivity, surjectivity, isometric).
2. I can't seem to show this. If I compute the $l^{p'}$ norm, I do not find a finite bound:
   $$\sum_n\vert y_n\vert^{p'}\leqslant\sum_n\Vert L\Vert_{(L^p)'}^{p'}\Vert e_n\Vert_{l^p}^{p'}$$
   I think the sequence will help me get the fact that $a_H$ is isometric ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here I consider $1<p<\infty$ and write $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ for some $1<q<\infty$.

Next let $F\in \ell_p'$ i.e. $F$ is a bounded or continuous real linear functional on $\ell_p$. Set, $$x_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n\big|F(e_j)\big|^{q-1} \operatorname{sgn}\big(F(e_j)\big)e_j.$$ Here, as usal $e_j$ is the sequence having $j$-th term as $1$ and all other terms of $e_j$ are zero. Also, for any real $r\in \Bbb R$ we define $$\operatorname{sgn}(r):=\begin{cases} 1&\text{ if }r\geq 0,\\ -1&\text{ if }r<0.\end{cases}$$ Now, $$\sum_{j=1}^n\big|F(e_j)\big|^{q}= F(x_n)\leq \big|F(x_n)\big|\leq \|F\|\cdot \|x_n\|_p=\|F\|\cdot \bigg(\sum_{j=1}^n\big|F(e_j)\big|^q\bigg)^{1/p}$$$$\implies \bigg(\sum_{j=1}^n\big|F(e_j)\big|^q\bigg)^{1/q}\leq \|F\|$$$$\implies \big\{F(e_j)\big\}_{j\geq 1}\in \ell_q\text{ as }n\in \Bbb N\text{ is arbitrary}.$$ Also, $$\ell_p\ni \{y_j\}_{j\geq 1}\overset{F}{\longmapsto}\sum_{j=1}^\infty y_j\cdot F(e_j)\in \Bbb R.$$

Comment: Great answer, thank you !